# Objective C: a C int array in a class interface?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, arrays, interface

I'm attempting to define a C `int` array as an instance variable in my class interface so that it can be accessed by any method in the class.

I tired writing

```
@interface aVCofMine : UIViewController{
   int[] myArray;
}
```

and

```
@interface aVCofMine : UIViewController{
   int myArray[];
}
```

but to no avail.

Is it actually possible to define a C array [instead of a NSArray] as an instance variable in the class interface?

Comment: the array size is not fixed.

Comment: @Arch Declare it like this, then: `int *myArray` It'll be up to you to allocate the memory for `myArray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C arrays need to be either dynamically allocated or fixed-size. So you can do:

```
@interface AVCOfMine : NSViewController {
    int myArray[5];
}
@end
```

or you can do

```
@interface AVCOfMine : NSViewController {
    int *myArray;
}
@end

@implementation AVCOfMine

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    myArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    free(myArray);
    [super dealloc]; // include this line only if not using ARC
}
@end
```

The former forces the array to always be of the same size. The latter allows you to choose the size at runtime, but is obviously a bit more complex. Which is better depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@interface aVCofMine : UIViewController{
   int *myArray;
}
```

Then, in your implementation code, in order to actually allocate the memory for your array:

```
myArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * numberOfElements);
```

And remember to free it `free(myArray);`